# Azure devops pipeline set a variable value based on other variable value

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a BRANCH_NAME variable based on the trigger branch which is working great. Now based on my BRANCH_NAME value I have to select a json file. Im using starts with but not sure why my TARGET_ENV is not working

```html
variables:
  system.debug: 'false'
  ${{ if startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 
'refs/heads/') }}:
    BRANCH_NAME: $[replace(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 
'refs/heads/', '')]
  ${{ if startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 
'refs/heads/feature') }}:
    BRANCH_NAME: $[replace(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 
'/', '-')]
  ###
  ${{ if eq(variables['BRANCH_NAME'], 'dev') }}:
    TARGET_ENV: dev
  ${{ if startsWith(variables['BRANCH_NAME'], 'test') }}:
    TARGET_ENV: test
  ${{ if or( startsWith(variables['BRANCH_NAME'], 'XX'), startsWith(variables['BRANCH_NAME'], 'VV') ) }}:
    TARGET_ENV: feature
```

And the value of  TARGET_ENV should be used in a script ( echo $TARGET_ENV )

Comment: *What* isn't working? What is the behavior you see?

Comment: its just cant find the env variable, im calling it in a bash script like echo $TARGET_ENV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The yaml file isn't executes as soon as an element is parted, the yaml file is parted in stages. During the template expansion stage only the variables set at queue time are available.

After the template has been expanded (e.g. the ${{}} blocks have been evaluated the yaml is interpreted top to bottom. So the value of BRANCH_NAME isn't available yet.

You can [set the variable either from a pre (like my variable tasks) or from a script by printing one of the special command statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74219499/736079).

```
    - bash: | 
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myVar;]foo" 
      condition: $[ eq(variables['BRANCH_NAME'], 'dev' ]
```

Or you can put all the logic in a single PowerShell block and let PowerShell evaluate the values of the variables.

```
- powershell: |
    if ($env:BRANCH_NAME -eq 'dev') {
      Write-host ##vso[task.setvariable variable=TARGET_ENV;]dev
    } 
    ...
    ...
```

This variable will only be available in the job the task runs. You can make it an output variable to make the task available in other jobs, but then you need to refer to it by its long name:

```
Dependencies.jobname.stepname.outputvariable
```

See also:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#about-tasksetvariable
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/73609482/736079

Comment: In that case should i add a script , use the same if condition and save as env variable ? can you tell me how can I achieve this ?

Comment: Thanks @jessehouwing that helped.  one last thing is , Im doing echo  $BRANCH_NAME and $TARGET_ENV in a shell script task: ShellScript@2. BRANCH_NAME o/p is good, but TARGET_ENV still o/p null.

Comment: I think the ; is missing  and quotes , can you add in your answer ?                                     - bash: |
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myVar;]foo"