# Programmatically get the $(rev:.r) variable in yaml scripts

Tags: azure-pipelines-yaml

This is a follow up of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74219392/pipeline-yaml-buildnumber-is-updated-but-the-build-description-doesnt-seem-to)

I'd like to put the number of my build in the description (and in other tasks), when using `BuildId` it works without any problem.

But if I use `$(rev:.r)`, this variable is not interpreted and I have an error saying that the number version is not correct (invalid characters such as $ and :).

Here's some code working with BuildId but not with Rev :

```
variables:
- group: NumVersion
- name: upperversion
  ${{ if eq(parameters.VersionBuild,'ReleaseProd') }}:
    value: $(1-VersionMajeur).$(2-VersionMineure-ReleaseProd)
  ${{ if eq(parameters.VersionBuild,'Release') }}:
    value: $(1-VersionMajeur).$(2-VersionMineure-Release)
  ${{ if eq(parameters.VersionBuild,'Develop') }}:
    value: $(1-VersionMajeur).$(2-VersionMineure-Dev)

- name: lowerversion
  ${{ if eq(parameters.TypeBuild,'Feature') }}:
    value: 99.$(Build.BuildId)
  ${{ if eq(parameters.TypeBuild,'Production') }}:
    value: $(3-VersionCorrective-Release).$(rev:.r)

name: $(upperversion).$(lowerversion)

stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: Prerequisites
    displayName: Prerequisites
    steps:
    - checkout: self
    - script: |
       echo '##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$(upperversion).$(lowerversion)
```

Did somebody encounter this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs you can’t use this variable other than in the build number / name field.

> In Azure DevOps $(Rev:r) is a special variable format that only works in the build number field. When a build is completed, if nothing else in the build number has changed, the Rev integer value increases by one.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops